# Using PatternSequence with Cases in Mathematica to find peaks

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, design-patterns

Given pairs of coordinates

```
data = {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}, 
        {6, 2}, {7, 3}, {8, 4}, {9, 3}, {10, 2}}
```

I'd like to extract peaks and valleys, thus:

```
{{4, 2}, {5, 1}, {8, 4}}
```

My current solution is this clumsiness:

```
Cases[
 Partition[data, 3, 1],
 {{ta_, a_}, {tb_, b_}, {tc_, c_}} /; Or[a < b > c, a > b < c] :> {tb, b}
]
```

which you can see starts out by tripling the size of the data set using `Partition`. I think it's possible to use `Cases` and `PatternSequence` to extract this information, but this attempt doesn't work:

```
Cases[
 data,
 ({___, PatternSequence[{_, a_}, {t_, b_}, {_, c_}], ___} 
         /; Or[a < b > c, a > b < c]) :> {t, b}
]
```

That yields `{}`.

I don't think anything is wrong with the pattern because it works with `ReplaceAll`:

```
data /. ({___, PatternSequence[{_, a_}, {t_, b_}, {_, c_}], ___} 
             /; Or[a < b > c, a > b < c]) :> {t, b}
```

That gives the correct first peak, `{4, 2}`. What's going on here?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ArgentoSapiens! Please vote-up answers you like using the vote buttons, and don't forget to accept the answer you like as the final answer using the checkmark button. You may want to wait a little for more answers to come in before doing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the reasons why your failed attempt doesn't work is that `Cases` by default looks for matches on level 1 of your expression. Since your looking for matches on level 0 you would need to do something like

```
Cases[
 data,
 {___, {_, a_}, {t_, b_}, {_, c_}, ___} /; Or[a < b > c, a > b < c] :> {t, b}, 
 {0}
]
```

However, this only returns `{4,2}` as a solution so it's still not what you're looking for.
To find all matches without partitioning you could do something like

```
ReplaceList[data, ({___, {_, a_}, {t_, b_}, {_, c_}, ___} /; 
    Or[a < b > c, a > b < c]) :> {t, b}]
```

which returns

```
{{4, 2}, {5, 1}, {8, 4}}
```

Comment: +1 There is no need to wrap the inner sequence in `PatternSequence` in the `ReplaceList` expression.

Comment: @WReach: yes you're right, that was a remainder of the original code. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Aha! The `levelspec` is part of what I was missing. Why does the "fixed" `Cases` implementation only return the first extremum?

Answer (score 5):

Your "clumsy" solution is fairly fast, because it heavily restricts what gets looked at.

Here is an example.

```
m = 10^4;
n = 10^6;

ll = Transpose[{Range[n], RandomInteger[m, n]}];

In[266]:= 
Timing[extrema = 
    Cases[Partition[ll, 3, 
      1], {{ta_, a_}, {tb_, b_}, {tc_, c_}} /; 
       Or[a < b > c, a > b < c] :> {tb, b}];][[1]]

Out[266]= 3.88

In[267]:= Length[extrema]

Out[267]= 666463
```

This seems to be faster than using replacement rules.

Faster still is to create a sign table of products of differences. Then pick entries not on the ends of the list that correspond to sign products of 1.

```
In[268]:= Timing[ordinates = ll[[All, 2]];
  signs = 
   Table[Sign[(ordinates[[j + 1]] - 
        ordinates[[j]])*(ordinates[[j - 1]] - ordinates[[j]])], {j, 2,
      Length[ll] - 1}];
  extrema2 = Pick[ll[[2 ;; -2]], signs, 1];][[1]]

Out[268]= 0.23

In[269]:= extrema2 === extrema

Out[269]= True
```

Handling of consecutive equal ordinates is not considered in these methods. Doing that would take more work since one must consider neighborhoods larger than three consecutive elements. (My spell checker wants me to add a 'u' to the middle syllable of "neighborhoods". My spell checker must think we are in Canada.)

Daniel Lichtblau

Answer (score 2):

This may be not exactly the implementation you ask, but along those lines:

```
ClearAll[localMaxPositions];
localMaxPositions[lst : {___?NumericQ}] := 
  Part[#, All, 2] &@
     ReplaceList[
        MapIndexed[List, lst], 
        {___, {x_, _}, y : {t_, _} .., {z_, _}, ___} /; x < t && z < t :> y];
```

Example:

```
In[2]:= test = RandomInteger[{1,20},30]
Out[2]= {13,9,5,9,3,20,2,5,18,13,2,20,13,12,4,7,16,14,8,16,19,20,5,18,3,15,8,8,12,9}

In[3]:= localMaxPositions[test]
Out[3]= {{4},{6},{9},{12},{17},{22},{24},{26},{29}}
```

Once you have positions, you may extract the elements:

```
In[4]:= Extract[test,%]
Out[4]= {9,20,18,20,16,20,18,15,12}
```

Note that this will also work for plateau-s where you have more than one same maximal element in a row. To get minima, one needs to trivially change the code. I actually think that `ReplaceList` is a better choice than `Cases` here.

To use it with your data:

```
In[7]:= Extract[data,localMaxPositions[data[[All,2]]]]
Out[7]= {{4,2},{8,4}}
```

and the same for the minima. If you want to combine, the change in the above rule is also trivial.

Comment: @Sjoerd I meant plateau-s, this was a typo. Thanks for pointing this out, had no intent to insult Plato.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

```
Part[#,Flatten[Position[Differences[Sign[Differences[#[[All, 2]]]]], 2|-2] + 1]] &@data

(* ==> {{4, 2}, {5, 1}, {8, 4}} *)

Extract[#, Position[Differences[Sign[Differences[#]]], {_, 2} | {_, -2}] + 1] &@data

(* ==> {{4, 2}, {5, 1}, {8, 4}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since one of your primary concerns about your "clumsy" method is the data expansion that takes place with Partition, you may care to know about the `` Developer` `` function [`PartitionMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Developer/ref/PartitionMap.html), which does not partition all the data at once.  I use `Sequence[]` to delete the elements that I don't want.

```
Developer`PartitionMap[
  # /. {{{_, a_}, x : {_, b_}, {_, c_}} /; a < b > c || a > b < c :> x,
        _ :> Sequence[]} &,
  data, 3, 1
]
```

Comment: +1, did not know about `ParitionMap`. Would have been handy in a lot of cases.

Comment: @rcollyer FWIW, I cleaned up my answer.